# How to install SwiftyJSON on osx

Tags: swift, cocoapods, swifty-json

I've tried creating a file with the following:

1. create Podfile

'

```
platform :osx, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'MyApp' do
    pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.2.0'
end
```

2. run command

   pod install

this is retuned:

```
Analyzing dependencies
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "SwiftyJSON":
  In Podfile:
    SwiftyJSON (~> 2.2.0)

Specs satisfying the `SwiftyJSON (~> 2.2.0)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.
```

I thought maybe it had to do with the platform so I go to the SwiftJSON documentation on CoCaoPods.org.

This is what I found

[image]

Oh look maybe instead of 'osx' it's expecting 'macOS'. I update my Podfile to this:

```
platform :macOS, '10.0'
use_frameworks!

target 'Maconomi' do
    pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.2.0'
end
```

and run the previous command again and get this error instead:

```
[!] Invalid `Podfile` file: Unsupported platform `macOS`. Platform must be `:ios`, `:osx`, `:tvos`, or `:watchos`..

 #  from /Users/travis.rivera/Documents/macOSAPP/Maconomi/Podfile:1
 #  -------------------------------------------
 >  platform :macOS, '10.0'
 #  use_frameworks!
 #  -------------------------------------------
```

so now I'm stuck.

Comment: I may be missing something here, but...isn't 10.0 less than 10.10?  Given how old 10.0 is, was that a typo?

Comment: changing 10.0 to 10.10 worked. It was a mistake but I wouldn't call it a typo.

Answer (score 0):

```
platform :osx, '10.10'
use_frameworks!

target 'MyApp' do
    pod 'SwiftyJSON', '~> 2.2.0'
end
```

then

> pod install

I missed the osx minimum version number.

Comment: For others you can use `:macos` as long as its all lower-case.